# String replace search and replace. How to do a substring of search hits

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, replace

I have this method, which inserts an anchor tag on every occurrence of @something. 
The anchor tag contains a href to the designated sub URL.

Here is the code

```
private generateAnchors(content: string) {
    return content.replace(/(@[^ @]+)/ig, '<a href="/home/user/$1">$1</a>');
}
```

This outputs a every occurrence of @something and generates the anchor tag. However I need to remove the '@' tag in the first insertion of $1, but not the last. How do I basicly do a .substring(1) on the first insertion of $1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work (capture only the part without the `@` and add it manually to the replacement part):

```
private generateAnchors(content: string) {
    return content.replace(/@([^ @]+)/ig, '<a href="/home/user/$1">@$1</a>');
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this works, just as the accepted answer

Comment: well it actually works quicker, there's no use to capture a part that never changes, it will always be `@`.. choice between pragmatism and generics i guess ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can divide your regex in order to have two elements : the `@` and the rest

```
private generateAnchors(content: string) {
    return content.replace(/(@)([^ @]+)/ig, '<a href="/home/user/$2">$1$2</a>');
}
```